# Nginx - redirect to VM ip from remote

Tags: redirect, nginx, docker, virtual-machine

I'm working on OSX with docker. Wihch install a light VM to makes containers run.

So my app is on the ip 192.168.99.100.

I would like to it my local IP on the host (192.168.1.10) and redirect to my vm.

I first my a 301 redirection to the VM IP but of course it's working well on my machine but not on a remote inside my network.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    return       301 http://192.168.99.100/;

    location = /info {
        allow   127.0.0.1;
        deny    all;
        rewrite (.*) /.info.php;
    }

    error_page  404     /404.html;
    error_page  403     /403.html;
}
```

What I have to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my own question.

I just have to had a proxy_pass to my local IP like this.

```
location / {
     proxy_pass http://192.168.99.100/;
    }
```

It was that easy.